# Searching for the right controller/action. PHP

Tags: php

There's a piece of code:

```
if(DataEndpoint::isAjaxRequest()) {
    if(isset($_POST['controller']) && !empty($_POST['controller']) && isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $controllerName = $_POST['controller'];
        $actionName = $_POST['action'];

        if(class_exists($controllerName.'Controller')) {
            $controller = new $controllerName.'Controller';

            if(method_exists($controller, $actionName)) {
                // if id's been passed
                // if method signature accepts the parameter
                // invoke... ?
            }
        }
    }
} // if(DataEndpoint::isAjaxRequest()) {
```

I can check whether given `action` exists but don't know how `to pass/invoke the action with` additional parameters like id (let's suggest it is a string and it is optional). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ReflactionClass and ReflactionMethod. look at here:

```
$action_ref = new ReflectionMethod($controller, $action);
$action_required_params = $action_ref->getParameters();
$parameters = array(/*...*/);
$action_ref->invokeArgs($controller, $parameters);
```

Comment: then call `ReflectionMethod::invoke`.